# Opposite of finish()

Tags: android

I know that finish() returns your activity back to your previous activity. Now I am curious if we are able to accomplish the opposite meaning forwarding back to the next activity that you backed off without doing an Intent. This is just a curiosity question.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so. I think after the finish the acticity is maintained by the GC and it is over. You should maintain your activities in your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The "next activity that you backed off without doing an Intent" was destroyed by a call to `finish()` when the user pressed BACK, so you cannot return to it.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible, once you run finish() (or press back) on an activity it will be poped from the activity stack and al its content garbage collected, only way to reach if again is by starting it with and intent.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, because The activity that finish()ed was destroyed.

Long answer: From the [Activity Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

> onDestroy()   - The final call you receive before your activity is
>   destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing
>   (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily
>   destroying this instance of the activity to save space.

Calling finish() doesn't actually guarantee immediate GC on the activity, but it will be made eligible soon after a call to finish(). You can assume that anything in the activity instance is gone if it wasn't persisted. Don't hold references to Activities that Android says should be killable, per [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), this is not a way to get around this, and is a Bad Idea(tm).

You could override OnDestroy() and check  isFinishing() if you'd like to store the activity history in your application, so that you can manually implement something like "forward" functionality, but in general it's better practice to do something like that in  onSaveInstanceState().

Answer (score 0):

NO,because once you call the finish() method,it will destroy that corresponding activity.The only way to accompanish your task is by using an intent.